# Div side by side in container compatible with IE using flexie

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, css

I am currently working on a css3/html5 project. Its working perfectly in chrome thanks to a previous question I asked, and the answer recommended using flexie (http://flexiejs.com/) but in IE not even close. Below is a screen of what it looks like in Chrome.

[image: Screenshot of google chrome]

and in IE it looks like the below

[image: Screenshot of IE]

I've added the code to http://jsfiddle.net/Ax6Xr/ if it helps.

I've added the below CSS as for some reason stackoverflow won't let me submit without posting some code which seems a bit pointless as I've linked to jsfiddle.

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#articleContainer {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#articleContent
{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#articleSideBar
{
    position: relative;
    width: 28%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}
```

and below is the HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="ArticleStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="../scripts/flexie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header>
                Header
            </header>
            <div id="articleContainer">

                <div id="articleContent" contenteditable>
                    The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. All good men must come to the aid of the party
                </div>

                <div id="articleSidebar">
                    Article Sidebar
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE is not yet HTML5 compatible. I believe IE10 will be.

Comment: IE9 is html5 compatible, my current website uses HTML5 and works in IE9, admitiddely IE9 isn't HTML5 perfect but it is supported

Comment: Well, its support for HTML5 is limited and certainly much lesser than Firefox, Chrome etc.
Specifically talking about your code, IE cannot support CSS classes such as `-webkit-...` Such styles only work on Webkit browsers(Chrome and Safari).

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to disagree, I'm using many CSS3 components such as border-radius and box-shadow using either the standard css3 name or using the -moz and -webkit alternatives and this also works in IE9

Answer (score 0):

Flexie looks for non-vendor-prefixed properties. For example, it will ignore -moz-box-pack, but not box-pack. For best results, make sure to use a non-vendor-prefixed property in addition to your prefixed properties.
Try adding: *display: box; box-flex: 1; ...*